# Codigo dentro de funcion Python no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un pqueño programa en python usando una funcion, el caso es que dentro de la funcion no funciona nada , en cambio si la quito si funciona al llamar a la funcion me sale el error **TypeError: is_divisible() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'n', 'x', and 'y'**.Si luego llamo a los varlores n x y igual me sale el error las variables no estan definidas el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    def is_divisible(n,x,y):
    #your code here
    n = int(input("Check number: "))
    x = int(input("Number 1: "))
    y = int(input("Number 2: "))
    


    if n % x and n % y <= 1 :
        print(n,"is not divisible by", x, "and", y)
    else:
        print("is divisible")

is_divisible()
```

Comment: a la función le pides 3 parámetros, pero al invocarla no le pones ninguno

Comment: La función no debería pedir al usuario los datos con que operar. En vez de eso, es el programa principal el que debería pedirlos y luego llamar a la función pasándole esos datos como parámetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `is_divisible()` está declarada con tres argumentos; tienes que llamarla con tres argumentos.

El código te funciona al eliminar `def is_divisible` porque ahora las lineas `input` ya no están encerradas dentro de la función; se ejecutan siempre.

Separa el input de los datos de los cálculos. Primero pide los tres valores; luego llama a la función.

```
def is_divisible(n, x, y):
    if n % x and n % y <= 1:
        print(n, "is not divisible by", x, "and", y)
    else:
        print("is divisible")

    # your code here
n = int(input("Check number: "))
x = int(input("Number 1: "))
y = int(input("Number 2: "))
    
is_divisible(n, x, y)
```

Funciona, pero no es lo optimo. Mejor aún es separar completamente las entradas/salidas de los cálculos, para asi quedar en libertad de producir cualquier salida y además poder automatizar las pruebas:

```
def is_divisible(n, x, y):
    return not (n % x or n % y)


pruebas = [[20, 7, 4],
           [20, 5, 4]]

for datos in pruebas:
    n = datos[0]
    x = datos[1]
    y = datos[2]
    if is_divisible(n, x, y):
        print("%d is divisible by %d and %d" % (n, x, y))
    else:
        print("%d is not divisible by %d and %d" % (n, x, y))
```

produce:

```
20 is not divisible by 7 and 4
20 is divisible by 5 and 4
```